# Postgres Query To Select a Column with the same value Where Values in another column are of a pre-defined subset

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the table below, I'm trying to find a way to get the *group* matching a pre-defined subset of *token*s BUT the group should not contain any tokens outside of the subset.

| group | token |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 37 |
| 1 | 34 |
| 1 | 32 |
| 3 | 32 |
| 3 | 34 |

Example: I want to select the group containing tokens (32, 34).
Problem: Doing a `GROUP BY group` and an `IN (32, 34)` condition will mean receiving both group 3 and group 1. However, group 3 should be omitted on the basis that it also has a `token` with value `37` which is not in my subset.

Efforts:

1. Attempted `string_agg` on the `token` column with different comparison operators which check the list of `group` columns that were selected based on `token` matching one value in my subset `(32, 34)`. This got messy very quickly and resulted in type conversions and elaborate string comparisons.
2. Attempted a nested query which would first extract a list of `group` ids as long as one of the `token` values were in my list, and then attempting to count the total `token` belonging to *group* and comparing it to the length of my subset. Due to the implementation of this table and how it's used, it would be a sufficient solution since I'm guaranteed no duplication of groups containing the specified token set but it is definitely not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a having clause to determine if the count distinct of in(32,34) is equal to 2 but also that the count for any other token is zero. e.g:

```
select
  group_id
from your_table
group by
  group_id
having count(distinct case when token in(32,34) then token end) = 2
and count(case when token not in(32,34) then 1 end) = 0
```

| group_id |
| --- |
| 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3UVbc-hF)

**nb** "not in()" can produce unexpected results if it encounters a null so I usually avoid it and so I have avoided that through the where clause. Here it is is not essential as tested at the fiddle above. Another approach without the where clause:

```
having count(case when token in(32,34) then 1 end) > 0
and count(case when coalesce(token,-1) not in(32,34) then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: Absolutely love the simplicity of your first suggestion. However, I will take into account what you mentioned about the potential results on NULL and determine which approach to take depending on my requirements. Thank you!

Comment: After some more edge case testing, your first solution actually doesn't work in the reverse. If I introduce a third item `37` to the subset, then it will return both groups 3 & 1.

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/Qf_ytPjT and I have edited the answer. Now it uses count distinct, which is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

If your set is in table `s` like below

```sql
create table s as
select 34 token union all
select 32 token;
```

And your table is `t`.

You can left join table `t` with table `s`.

```sql
select t.group_, s.token
from   t
       left join s
       on s.token = t.token;
```

| group_ | token |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 |
| 3 | 32 |
| 1 | 34 |
| 3 | 34 |
| 3 | (null) |

You can see null in token column of `s` table. That null means `37` value not exists in `s` table.

Now you need to exclude by changing null to -1 (or whatever value smaller than any values) and check it in having statement.

```sql
select t.group_, min(coalesce(s.token, -1)) min_token
from   t
       left join s
       on s.token = t.token
group by t.group_
having min(coalesce(s.token, -1)) != -1;
```

| group_ | min_token |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 |

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cc1cb9/8

Comment: Very interesting approach, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done rather easy using arrays:

```
SELECT  "group"
FROM    t1
GROUP BY "group"
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(token ORDER BY token ASC) = ARRAY[32,34];
```

The sort order of both arrays must be the same. That's why the function array_agg() is ordering the tokens and the list of tokens you're looking for (32 and 34) must be sorted as well. You could do this in a subquery or CTE, if needed.